# Generate a powerset of a set containing only subsets of a certain size

Tags: erlang, set, subset, powerset

I would like to generate a powerset `P(S)` of a set `S`. I would like `P(S)` to have only subsets equal to a certain size.

For example, if we have `S = [1,2,3,4]`, then `limited_powerset(S,3)` will be `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,4]].`

[Hynek Pichi Vychodil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49197/hynek-pichi-vychodil) has provided a nice example of general powerset generation in Erlang (thanks!):

```
generate([]) -> [[]];
generate([H|T]) -> PT = generate(T),
  generate(H, PT, PT).

generate(_, [], Acc) -> Acc;
generate(X, [H|T], Acc) -> generate(X, T, [[X|H]|Acc]).
```

**How can I modify it to have only subsets of a certain size?** Introducing a Limit variable and changing the last line to

```
case length([X|H]) < Limit of
        true -> 
            ps(X, T, Acc, Limit);
        false -> 
            ps(X, T, [[X|H]|Acc],Limit)
    end.
```

doesn't help.

P.S. I guess that the number of subsets will be less than N!, but how can I calculate it exactly?

Comment: If it only includes some subsets of the given set, it _isn't_ the powerset.

Comment: @Alexey I'm sure some mathematician, somewhere, has a name for such a subset of a powerset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
limited_powerset(L, N) ->
  {_, Acc} = generate(L, N),
  Acc.

generate([], _) ->
  {[[]], []};
generate([H|T], N) ->        
  {PT, Acc} = generate(T, N),
generate(H, PT, PT, Acc, N).

generate(_, [], PT, Acc, _) -> 
  {PT, Acc};
generate(X, [H|T], PT, Acc, N) when length(H)=/=N-1 ->
  generate(X, T, [[X|H]|PT], Acc, N);
generate(X, [H|T], PT, Acc, N) ->    
  generate(X, T, [[X|H]|PT], [[X|H]|Acc], N).
```

It's not trivial.  It had me stumped for a while.  The trick is that you need to maintain the full powerset accumulator throughout the algorithm and create a second accumulator for the limited set.

Comment: dsmith, thank you! This works, however I had to mention in the question that I need the limit for two reasons: (a) there is no need for all subsets which are not of length N and (b) I thought I could overcome the memory efficiency problem (the powerset takes 2^n space) by filtering out small subsets before adding them to the accumulator.

Comment: So many years after you wrote this, I hope you'll be able to revisit the solutions and answer a silly question - what does the name 'PT' represent? Hopefully that'll allow me to understand the solution.  Because at this point I simply don't get what generate/2 is supposed to accomplish, seeing how there's no code "assembling" the results of the previous calls... generate/5 at least does something with the ACC =) But, the code bloody works, so I must push on and figure it out! =)

Comment: alexakarpov, I'm using the variable names of from the OP, but it seems to me to mean "the Powerset of T", or "the Powerset of the Tail".